# Issue running an Azure Function from a package

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Updated - see notes below

---

I have a .NET 8 Azure Function (Windows, not Linux) that is triggered by a CRON timer.

I published it to a Local Folder:

- Configuration : Release
- Target Framework : net8.0
- Target Runtime : win-x64
- Deployment mode : Self-contained

And then deployed it to the wwwroot folder and it's working fine.

From the "Diagnose and solve problems" pane of the App Service, it gave me a warning that I should deploy this using the "Run Frm Package approach".

I added the configuration value `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` with a value of "1" and that made the wwwroot folder read-only, so that seemed to have been set correctly.

I then deployed the exact same set of files to the "SitePackages" folder and restarted the App Service.  It reported that it has restarted successfully.

The only problem is that my functions no longer fires.

I didn't set the `URL` because it's not Linux and is in the default SitePackages folder.  The zip is well under the 1GB limit.

---

### Update 18-Dec-2023

Based on the comment by @PravallikaKV, I have some more information.

### Isolated rather than In process

.NET 8 wasn't fully released when this project started, so I went with the isolated model.  This is a copy of the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>     
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.3" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### Publish profile

[image]

### Configuration

#### Application Settings

[image]

#### Function runtime settings

[image]

#### General Settings

[image]

### Exception

When I run this as a package, I now see the following error message:

> Full Exception :
> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionMetadataManager.GetFallbackWorkerConfig() at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataManager.cs : 129
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionMetadataManager.LoadFunctionMetadata(Boolean forceRefresh,Boolean includeCustomProviders,IFunctionInvocationDispatcher dispatcher,IList`1 workerConfigs) at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataManager.cs : 137 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionMetadataManager.GetFunctionMetadata(Boolean forceRefresh,Boolean applyAllowList,Boolean includeCustomProviders,IList`1 workerConfigs) at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataManager.cs : 90
> at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Management.FunctionsSyncManager.GetSyncTriggersPayload() at /*/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Management/FunctionsSyncManager.cs : 312
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Management.FunctionsSyncManager.TrySyncTriggersAsync(Boolean isBackgroundSync) at /*/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Management/FunctionsSyncManager.cs : 125

Comment: Are you able to see the trigger in the function app? Please share the error details if you are getting any.

Comment: Hi @PravallikaKV.  Yes, it showed all the functions, but no errors.

Comment: Did you try running the deployed function?

Comment: "Did you try running the deployed function?".  Wasn't aware that was possible since it's on a CRON timer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with the poster and resolved this offline.

The drag and drop functionality in Kudu doesn’t actually use ZipDeploy.
You would need to invoke Zip Deploy either via Visual Studio and Publish or VS Code and Deploy Function App or CLI or the Rest API’s.

[Zip push deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) | Microsoft Learn has more on this.

Answer (score 1):

- Check the logs if there are any error messages which might be causing the function to fail.
- Check if your function code is compatible with the .NET 8 runtime.

I have replicated the same in my environment with the below steps:

- Created a **.NET 8 Isolated** Azure function with **Timer Trigger**.
- Deployed the function to the newly created Azure function app with the below options:
  - OS: Windows
  - Runtime Stack: .NET 8 Isolated Process (Early Access)
  - Deployment-Mode: Self-Contained

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Application Settings of my Function App:**

[image]
[image]

- Navigate to the `deployed function=>Code+Test`, click on `Test/Run`.

[image]

```cs
Connected! You are now viewing logs of Function runs in the current Code + Test panel. To see all the logs for this Function, please go to 'Monitor' from the Function menu.
2023-12-13T09:40:02Z [Information] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=f83e5e82-e8b4-45f7-b582-d305c2d83f96)
2023-12-13T09:40:02Z [Information] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 12/13/2023 9:40:02 AM
2023-12-13T09:40:02Z [Information] Next timer schedule at: 12/13/2023 9:45:00 AM
2023-12-13T09:40:02Z [Information] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=f83e5e82-e8b4-45f7-b582-d305c2d83f96, Duration=10ms)
```

- Check if the function is running without any issues.
- Navigate to the ***Monitor*** in left pane, Check the ***Invocation Traces***:
- I could see my **deployed Timer Trigger function getting fired** for every 5 minutes.

[image]

Comment: A NullReferenceException is thrown for "SyncTriggers operation failed".  I've updated details in my original post.  One difference between mine and yours is that for the Settings, only my `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` has the Deployment slot setting enabled.  All the others are unset.  Not sure if this matters?